# Swift get the difference between current date and hours:minutes:seconds as a String

Tags: ios, swift

in my app I get a JSON response as a string -> `"16:00:00"`
What I want to do is to get the timeInterval in seconds from the current date until "16:00:00"

this is my code so far. PS sorry for the bad description, thanks for your help

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:task.start) {

       print(date.timeDifference(date: Date()))

    }



func timeDifference(date: Date) -> String {

        let hourMinuteSecond: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents(hourMinuteSecond, from: date, to: self);

        let seconds = "\(difference.second ?? 0)s"
        let minutes = "\(difference.minute ?? 0)m" + " " + seconds
        let hours = "\(difference.hour ?? 0)h" + " " + minutes


        if let hour = difference.hour, hour       > 0 { return hours }
        if let minute = difference.minute, minute > 0 { return minutes }
        if let second = difference.second, second > 0 { return seconds }
        return ""
    }
```

Comment: hh (1-12) without AM PM it doesn't make any sense. You should use HH (0-23)

Comment: @LeoDabus stil not working

Comment: I didn't even looked at your implementation. Btw drop the NS from `NSCalendar`. You should use `Calendar` since Swift 3

Comment: @LeoDabus could you please help me solving this ?

Comment: I can but not right now. You will probably get a response before I get a chance to help you later.

Comment: Why not use `timeIntervalSinceNow`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. Here's one:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
df.defaultDate = Date() // default to today's date
if let date = df.date(from:task.start) {
    print(date.timeDifference(date: Date()))
}

func timeDifference(date: Date) -> String {
    let diff = timeIntervalSince(date)

    let fmt = DateComponentsFormatter()
    fmt.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    let res = fmt.string(from: diff)

    return res
}
```

This code assumes that `timeDifference` is an extension method of `Date`.

Also note that this will give a negative time difference if the time in the string is earlier than "now". If you want a positive time difference no matter if the time string is before or after "now", use the `abs` function:

```
    let res = fmt.string(from: abs(diff))
```

Comment: You will get a negative time difference if the time in the string is earlier than "now". If you want a positive time difference whether the time is before or after "now", use `abs`. See my updated answer.